# jquery triggerhandler not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery

the trigger below never call. The alert on call never pop up.
It was triggered by these statements. See second block.
   $('#sCart').trigger('add', {
                            stock_id: stock_id

```
 $('#sCart').on('add', function(event, data) {  
    alert('on add');
    $.ajax({
        url: '$subCartUpdate'.replace('$tokenHolder', Math.random()),
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader('if-Modified-Since', '0');
        },
        success: function(success, statusText, jqXHR) {
            alert(statusText);
            $('#sCart').trigger('clear');
            $('#sCart').html(success.subCart);               

            if(timerId === null) {  
                $('#sCart').queue('add', function() {
                    $(this).fadeIn(function() {
                        $(this).dequeue('add');
                    });
                });                  
            } else {  
                clearTimeout(timerId);                  
            }
            timerId = setTimeout(function() {
                $('#sCart').fadeOut();
                timerId = null;
            }, 7000);                            

            $('#sCart').queue('add', function() {
                var updatedItemSelector = '#stock_'+data.stock_id;
                var updatedItem = $(updatedItemSelector).fadeOut(500);               
                updatedItem.fadeIn(2000, function() {
                    $(this).dequeue('add');  
                });                  
            });               

            if(success.reservedTimeStamp) {
                $('#sCartTimer').trigger('start', {timer: success.reservedTimeStamp});
            }

            $('#sCart').dequeue('add');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, statusText, errors) {
            var i = 0;
        }
    });      
});
```

It was triggered from code below.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '$addUrl',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: stock_id,
                amount: amount
            },
            success: function(success, statusText, jqXHR) {
                    alert(statusText);
                if(success.reload) {
                    location.reload(true);
                } else if(success.redirect) {
                    location.href = success.redirect;
                } else {
                            $('#sCart').trigger('add', {
                        stock_id: stock_id                  
                    });
                    $('.product-amount').val(1); 
                    //$('.type .selected').first().trigger('click');  
                    $('.stock_left').trigger('update');
                    $('.purchase').trigger('unblock');                    
                }                                
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, statusText, error) {
                var i = 0;
            }
        });
```

Comment: do you even get the ajax data returned?? does it ever end in **Success** function?

Comment: What exactly is `add`, first it looks like a custom event that you somehow created, then it's apparently the name of a custom animation queue? Seems it's both, but it's a little confusing when you use the same name ?